# Matlab: Access the same element in all stacked structures

Tags: matlab, stack, structure

I have a stacked structure with data, that looks something like this:

```
a(1) = struct('X',rand(10,1),'Y',rand(10,1),'Time',(1:1:10)')
a(2) = struct('X',rand(10,1),'Y',rand(10,1),'Time',(1:1:10)')
```

(The Number of stacked structures and the length of every parameter is not constant)

Now I'd like to access all the X data with timestamp 5.
I know that I can do this with a loop:

```
data = zeros(length(a),1)
for k=1:1:length(a)
    data(k) = a(k).X(5)
end
```

But I wonder if there isn't a way to access the data without a loop?

I tried `b = [ a(:).X(5) ]` but this doesn't work (`b = [ a(:).X ]` does). I already have to do this in an encircling loop, so I'd like to avoid needless calculations...

And in the same topic: Is it possible to get all data of one stack with the same timestamp?
Something like this:

```
data = a(1)(a(1).Time==5)
>> data
data =
     <X value>    <Y value>    5
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what [`getfield`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html) is for!

```
data = getfield( a, {1:numel(a)}, 'X', {5} );
```

Comment: This only returns the first value (equal to "data = a(1).X(5)")? However, if I enter "data = getfield(a,{1:numel(a)},'X',{5:6})", I get the two values ( a(1).X(5) and a(1).X(6) ). Any idea?

Comment: @user1822048 reed the manual - this is a very powerful command to access structs.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
allDataX = [a(:).X];
allDataX(5, :) % the fifth row of all the Xs
```

As for your second question, you could do something like this

```
allTimes = [a.Time];
allDataX(allTimes == 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

### One liner solutions

Equivalently to `[a(:).X(5)]`, you can use [`subsref()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) to perform `[a.X](5,:)`:

```
subsref([a.X], substruct('()',{5,':'}))
```

Similarly, `a(1)(a(1).Time == 5)` can be done with `[a(1).X a(1).Y a(1).Time](a(1).Time == 5,:)`:

```
subsref(cell2mat(struct2cell(a(1))'), substruct('()',{a(1).Time == 5,':'}))
ans =
    0.6324    0.8003    5.0000
```

### A better approach

I assume that each timestamp has a pair of coordinates, which means that you can store your structure as:

```
data = [a(1).X a(1).Y a(1).Time];
```

This would make indexing much easier:

```
data(:,5)
data(data(:,3)==5,:)
```

You can store different sets of coordinates in a cell array:

```
data = {[a(1).X a(1).Y a(1).Time]
        [a(2).X a(2).Y a(2).Time]
        ...};

data{1}(:,5)
data{1}(data{1}(:,3)==5,:)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for the moment, though I'm trying to get Shai's approach to work (with 'getfield')...